# Saving vectors into a matrix matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have a bunch of arrays that I have generated from a loop

```
Peaks [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
Latency [23,24,25,26,27] etc.
```

I want to put all of those in a matrix that will look like that:

```
Peaks Latency
1      23
2      24
3      25
4      26
5      27
```

Then I'll want to save this as a text file.

It seems like it would be fairly simple but can't seem to find anything that closely speaks to me right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concatentate:

```
>> Peaks = [1 2 3 4 5];
>> Latency = [23 24 25 26 27];
>> T = [Peaks(:) Latency(:)]
T =
     1    23
     2    24
     3    25
     4    26
     5    27
```

Write:

```
fileName = 'PeaksLatency.txt';
hdr = {'Peaks','Latency'}
txt = sprintf('%s\t',hdr{:}); txt(end) = [];
dlmwrite(fileName,txt,'');                         % write header
dlmwrite(fileName,T,'-append','delimiter','\t');   % append data
```

Comment: SUper! That works perfectly. So simple as well why didn't I think of this.
Cheeky question, given an array ``[12 2 13 1 14 15 1]`` how can I get a new array in the same order but with ``1`` & ``2`` skipped/removed. Cheers!

Comment: @Bastien That would make a good question, but try `y = x(~ismember(x,[1 2]))`.

Comment: I've just gone on and asked it from scratch because I realised asking this unrelated thing in a comment is probably not a very good thing to do since other people might not see it. I'll try that though!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code

```
Peaks = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].';
Latency = [23,24,25,26,27].';

T = table(Peaks, Latency);

writetable(T,'table.txt', 'Delimiter', '\t');
```

Note that you need to make `Peaks` and `Latency` into column vectors (use `.'` operator).

Ref: http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/writetable.html

Comment: The `table` data type is new in [Matlab version 2013b](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2013/09/10/introduction-to-the-new-matlab-data-types-in-r2013b/).

Comment: Ok thanks! That works too! & So simple as well! Thanks a bunch!